# What are the use cases for developer console command line interface?

Tags: developer-console

I've accidentally discovered command line interface in developer console by pressing CTRL+Shift+L (although it is in console documentation).

You can set the interface to full screen by typing `set -f`, execute any of your class methods by typing `exec className.methodName(parameters);`

Or just run `exec system.debug('string');` which results you'd find in logs. You can apparently search for logs but I was not able to find anything.

**Edit**: sometimes publicSymbols works giving me a [massive list](http://pastebin.com/NvZQfzQD) of all available API calls. It could be potentially useful if console had `grep` function ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command line interface was a pet project. The idea was to provide convenient ways to preform different actions. The long term goal was to have anything possible in the dev console possible in the command line, as well as allow force.com developers to add commands. Eventually creating a community of command line tools.

The current commands are not useful, and it isn't really used by anyone. Those commands were just an initial set to show the concept. However, it never got traction and priorities eventually downed out the project. I don't think any development has been done on it since initial checkin.

If it did get traction, grep was definitely on the list to add. Another useful tool would be to stream content from existing and incoming logs. For example, let's say you are logging a user who is generating a lot of logs and all you want to see is debug statements and exceptions. Something like the following would not only grep all the existing logs generated by the user, but also grep any new logs generated by the user:

```
stream logs test@test.com | grep 'DEBUG\|exception'
```

Or maybe you just set a couple heapdump and you really only care about one variable. You could do something like:

```
exec className.methodName(parameters);
stream heaps className | show myVariable
```

And even better, if that list of commands started to get too long, the developer could string a list of commands into a new command and share it, or write their own using javascript and share that. That was the dream.

Comment: Thank you Thomas. That exactly what it looks like - a pet project :) I guess I could roll my own class to add new fields to objects like `exec cn.create(objectname,fieldname,length);`

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea. Also, note that you can create fields on objects in apex autocomplete. i.e. you should be able to do "Account a; a.fieldname" in apex, then press ctrl+space to bring up the autocomplete, and one of the options should be to create a field. At least you use to be able to.

Comment: Yup that works. This is insanely useful! Thanks Thomas.

Answer (score 0):

type commands you can see list of commands.

type help

it will give details about the command.

Comment: It does not help with `find` command missing syntax.