# Unable to open the Developer Console's command line window

Tags: developer-console

I'm unable to open Developer Console's command line window (`CTRL+SHIFT+L`) in both Chrome 73 and Firefox 66. Oddly though, this seems to work just fine in Internet Explorer 11.

If I open *Chrome's* developer console I see the following errors being logged:

[image]

However it's not just the `CTRL+SHIFT+L` shortcut that's broken, `CTRL+G` to goto a line in the code editor is also broken and some other shortcuts.

I've done all the usual things such as disable my plugins, log out/in, close/re-open my browser. My Salesforce session is also running in a different browser user profile where these extensions are disabled.

The same thing happens in both a Developer account and an Enterprise account.

Is this a bug in Salesforce's client side Javascript, are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that the [Developer Console Command Line](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=code_dev_console_command_line.htm) is largely an abandon pet project from several years ago - see [What are the use cases for developer console command line interface?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/66762/102).

That you can even access it via the keyboard shortcut is likely an oversight. For example, you can't actually access it via the developer console menus. There probably isn't much advantage to accessing it anymore. Instead you should be looking at the SFDX CLI.

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up Daniel. Bit of a Salesforce noob here and SFDX is next on my list of stuff to learn.